# login not redirecting in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

```
 public function login() {
         if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
            }
        }
    }
```

this is my login script and

```
  public $components = array('Acl', 'Session',
        'Auth' => array('authorize' => array('Controller'),
                        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard'),
                        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
                        'authenticate' => array('Form' => array('fields' => array('username' => 'email')))

        )
    );
```

this is auth compnents in appcontroller.php

it is logging in using email and password but it is not redirecting to user/dashboard

but instead of that if i put any external urls it redirects perfectly

```
eg:  'loginRedirect' => 'http://google.com',
```

it redirects to google

i am totally lost.kindly help

Comment: if you check most likely you _are_ redirecting to the loginRedirect, and then immediately redirecting back to the login screen (why, is for you to find out - it's an app error of some kind).

Comment: @AD7six: below answer fixed it. thanks for your valuable time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are allowed to view the dashboard page using: `AuthComponent::allow()`:

Add this method to your controller:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('dashboard');
}
```

<s>Make sure there is a route set for the dashboard page</s>

Comment: where should i give point one code? why should i have a rout set for that. i have  public function dashboard() {} in my users controller

Comment: I think you should use: `$this->Auth->allow('dashboard');` to allow the dashboard action. I added the code to my answer.